# chrome bug, onclick event inhibited when select control causes parent to scroll

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, select, onclick, scroll

This is a tricky one to describe but here goes.

A select control with a size > 1 is positioned in the browser down the bottom of the screen such that there is a scrollbar present in the body and only the first item in the select control is visible (the other items are there but you need to scroll the page down to see them).  There is an onclick event in the  select box or any parent above it but such does not fire when the select is clicked the first time.  What happens is that chrome automagically scrolls the page to show all the items in the select, but apparently forgets to pass the click event to the handler.

This behavior only seems to occur in chrome. (works fine in FF and IE)

Chrome developers are notoriously slow to fix bugs and especially given the obscure nature in this case, I suspect it will never be fixed.

Using setTimeout in the onfocus event (in addition to the onclick event) solves the problem as the onfocus doesnt seem to be inhibited.  However I would like to find a less hacky solution if there is one.

Ideas?